# Can I use "As an inspiration, we briefly ..." to start a paragraph talking about the prospect？

Tags: sentence-starts

I'm writing the last paragraph of a scientific paper. Does the opening sentence of "As an inspiration, we..." sound natural if I want to talk about something about the prospect of my present research?

Comment: Who or what are you intending to inspire? I think we need more information before weighing in on the appropriateness of the usage.

Comment: @user888379 I'm writing about TMD materials (a two-dimensional materials similar to graphene). It can be used in the future in many aspects.  I want to inspire the reader who will read my article.

Comment: Something like "we hope this research will inspire..." sounds the sort of thing you would read at the end of a paper.

Comment: It sounds natural enough for the reader but what you are asking is "Does it sound *professional* enough in a scientific paper, not a commercial advertisement?" No it does not. I agree with Stuart F (again) and recommend his phrase. Rely on the *research* to inspire, not your exuberant phrasing.

Comment: According to your wording of just four words, the inspiration is *we*. *We serve as an inspiration*. Perhaps you mean "As an inspiration, our research..."? But then @Elliot has it with letting the research inspire rather than telling me you wish it would. Similarly, you toot your own horn in a CV, then lay on the humility at the interview. *Yes, we found the research inspiring ourselves, but what a team we had!*